# Meaning of abbreviations (DP, KP, NP, RP) concerning POWER OFF RESET REASON in logcat / bugreport

Tags: usb-debugging, reboot, logging, shutdown

I have a Samsung Galaxy A7 2018 phone, and it is subject to frequent unexpected reboots/shutdowns. To try and pinpoint their cause, I extracted bugreports using `adb bugreport`.

In the main bugreport log file (`bugreport-yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss.txt`), the `POWER OFF RESET REASON` part lists all shutdowns and reboots, like so:

```
------ POWER OFF RESET REASON (/data/log/power_off_reset_reason.txt: 2018-12-06 13:16:36) ------
18/11/29 18:20:28
reason : userrequested
java.lang.Exception: It is not an exception!! just save the trace for process which called shutdown thread!! ShutdownThread.shutdown
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdownInner(ShutdownThread.java:590)
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.reboot(ShutdownThread.java:1755)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerService.lambda$-com_android_server_statusbar_StatusBarManagerService_30308(StatusBarManagerService.java:921)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.$m$0(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:728)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:547)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2018-11-29 18:21:12 |RP| reboot,userrequested

18/11/29 20:04:10
reason : userrequested
java.lang.Exception: It is not an exception!! just save the trace for process which called shutdown thread!! ShutdownThread.shutdown
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdownInner(ShutdownThread.java:590)
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.reboot(ShutdownThread.java:1755)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerService.lambda$-com_android_server_statusbar_StatusBarManagerService_30308(StatusBarManagerService.java:921)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.$m$0(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:728)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:547)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2018-11-29 20:04:55 |RP| reboot,userrequested

18/11/30 09:05:54
reason : userrequested
java.lang.Exception: It is not an exception!! just save the trace for process which called shutdown thread!! ShutdownThread.shutdown
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdownInner(ShutdownThread.java:590)
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.reboot(ShutdownThread.java:1755)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerService.lambda$-com_android_server_statusbar_StatusBarManagerService_30308(StatusBarManagerService.java:921)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.$m$0(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:728)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:547)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2018-11-30 09:06:42 |RP| reboot,userrequested

2018-12-01 12:42:11 |KP|
2018-12-01 13:57:04 |KP|
2018-12-02 19:09:10 |KP|
2018-12-03 10:41:29 |KP|
2018-12-04 00:49:28 |KP|
2018-12-04 13:57:20 |DP|
2018-12-04 14:58:17 |KP|
2018-12-04 21:49:20 |DP|
2018-12-05 09:08:20 |KP|
2018-12-05 09:25:19 |KP|
18/12/05 09:26:58
reason : userrequested
java.lang.Exception: It is not an exception!! just save the trace for process which called shutdown thread!! ShutdownThread.shutdown
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdownInner(ShutdownThread.java:590)
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdown(ShutdownThread.java:423)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerService.lambda$-com_android_server_statusbar_StatusBarManagerService_29827(StatusBarManagerService.java:901)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4.$m$0(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:728)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:547)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2018-12-05 09:28:37 |NP|
18/12/05 10:43:09
reason : userrequested
java.lang.Exception: It is not an exception!! just save the trace for process which called shutdown thread!! ShutdownThread.shutdown
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdownInner(ShutdownThread.java:590)
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.reboot(ShutdownThread.java:1755)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerService.lambda$-com_android_server_statusbar_StatusBarManagerService_30308(StatusBarManagerService.java:921)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.$m$0(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:728)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:547)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2018-12-05 10:44:37 |RP| reboot,userrequested

2018-12-05 12:07:33 |KP|
2018-12-05 12:22:23 |KP|
2018-12-05 14:38:07 |KP|
2018-12-05 15:58:46 |KP|
2018-12-05 20:04:40 |KP|
2018-12-05 21:23:00 |DP|
2018-12-05 21:39:37 |DP|
2018-12-06 00:49:24 |DP|
2018-12-06 01:29:54 |KP|
2018-12-06 01:45:55 |KP|
2018-12-06 03:52:06 |DP|
2018-12-06 04:03:02 |KP|
2018-12-06 04:06:40 |KP|
2018-12-06 04:16:19 |KP|
2018-12-06 05:11:56 |DP|
2018-12-06 05:34:23 |KP|
2018-12-06 05:46:28 |KP|
2018-12-06 06:36:42 |KP|
2018-12-06 06:44:33 |KP|
2018-12-06 07:17:01 |DP|
2018-12-06 07:37:15 |KP|
2018-12-06 08:09:17 |DP|
2018-12-06 08:15:15 |KP|
2018-12-06 09:36:32 |KP|
2018-12-06 10:16:25 |KP|
2018-12-06 10:25:01 |KP|
18/12/06 11:26:37
reason : userrequested
java.lang.Exception: It is not an exception!! just save the trace for process which called shutdown thread!! ShutdownThread.shutdown
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.shutdownInner(ShutdownThread.java:590)
    at com.android.server.power.ShutdownThread.reboot(ShutdownThread.java:1755)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerService.lambda$-com_android_server_statusbar_StatusBarManagerService_30308(StatusBarManagerService.java:921)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.$m$0(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.server.statusbar.-$Lambda$-TUoAzP8agiJJX9P4eGDtNXdVZ4$2.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:728)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:547)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2018-12-06 11:27:30 |RP| reboot,userrequested

2018-12-06 13:16:36 |DP|

------ 0.005s was the duration of 'POWER OFF RESET REASON' ------
```

From this log, we can see 4 different "types" of shutdowns:

- `DP`: ?
- `KP`: `Kernel Panic`?
- `NP`: ? Seems to correspond to user (or system)-requested shutdowns.
- `RP`: ? Seems to correspond to user (or system)-requested reboots.

**What is the meaning of those acronyms, and what do they correspond to?**